# Illustrated children’s book with Ewok like creatures crashing spaceship in a forest

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I work in a library and we had a young patron give us a description of a children's picture book that she can't remember the title of.

She's been looking for this book for a long time and no one seems to be able to make sense of what she's provided. It would have been helpful to have a date on this book but she's only in 5th grade so I don't think book dates are something she would stop to look at.

This is exactly what she wrote:

- Fantasy/scifi Children's Picture Book
- Little girl and "ewok" type creature (but not actual ewoks) with red head bandana crash land their saucer spaceship into the forest
- more "ewoks" come and surround them with blue and yellow bandanas (or maybe red?)
- Castle with  an evil queen, possibly a witch and a jail with monsters in it
- little green men (goblins?)
- princess
- good goblins and bad alien space creatures
- white book cover

Comment: There is a movie that is familiar to this,  battle for endor? I think

Answer (score 3):

I can't find anything that exactly matches the description or the white book cover, but there are a couple of tie-in children's books to The Ewok Adventure films (*Caravan of Courage & Battle for Endor*), such as

[The Ring, the Witch, and the Crystal:](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Ring,_the_Witch,_and_the_Crystal:_An_Ewok_Adventure)

> The Ring, The Witch, and The Crystal: An Ewok Adventure was a
>   children's book that was released in 1986 and tied in with the TV
>   movie, Ewoks: The Battle for Endor.

[image: book]

and adaptation of the novel with a record, [The Battle of Endor (book-and-record)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ewoks:_The_Battle_for_Endor_(book-and-record))

---

There is also a 2013 Dark Horse Comic that features the Ewoks and the Night Sister (witch), Charel (a female villain featured in *The Battle for Endor*), [Ewoks: Shadow of Endor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Ewoks%E2%80%94Shadows_of_Endor)

What's also sort of interesting about your description, is that the Ewok cartoon series, which also spawned children's books, did feature green fury goblin-like characters called Duloks *and* some of the Ewok's hood's/headwear were more "pop-colored" with Princess Kneesa wearing a pink hood or there was a transition with Wicket wearing a green one at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I remember a made-for-television movie that matches, which is "The Ewok Adventure" (Caravan of courage).  Maybe they made a picture book from it.  You can find the movie description [here](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087225).

["The Ewok Adventure"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089110/) is a followup TV Movie